# org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I want to give permission of URL access according to user roles. I have tried to execute my program but I unable to execute my program, I am facing ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter errors.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartcontactmanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smartcontactmanager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
        
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.0</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

MyConfig.java:
This is my configuration class.

```
package com.smartcontactmanager.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    //To Encrypt password
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    //Method configuration.
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                 .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                 .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                 .and().formLogin().and().csrf().disable();
     }


}
```

Errors:
I am facing this issues.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exceptio
n with message: class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.spri
ngframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.compare(FilterComparator.java:57) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1
.6.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:1108) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.
6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config
-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.
6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config
-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.
6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spri
ng-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>) ~[sp
ring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.
RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:257) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.2
.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-sec
urity-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It is conflicting with the dependencies provided by `spring-boot-starter-security`. Additionally, Spring Boot 3 uses Spring Security 6 and the jakarta namespace instead of javax.